# Web API runs on Visual Studio but not when deployed on IIS

Tags: c#, iis, async-await, asp.net-web-api2

I'm doing some research on integration with CIDR/Aadhaar systems (Indian system for unique identification of individuals). I chose the Nuget package which was the only available option that I found. The package data is present [here](http://souvikdc9.github.io/aadhaarapi.net/).

I developed a console application to test the code and I got successful results for the test data provided by [CIDR](https://authportal.uidai.gov.in/web/uidai/developer). I then proceeded to develop a Web API 2 for the same and it worked perfectly the same way when I ran the project from Visual Studio (which uses IIS Express). But after deploying it to IIS, I get the following exception (I had downloaded the source of the package from Nuget to pinpoint the cause):

```
[2017-02-07 11:52:44:434]  http://localhost/AadhaarAPI/api/Aadhaar : Type : System.AggregateException
[2017-02-07 11:52:44:434]  http://localhost/AadhaarAPI/api/Aadhaar : Error : One or more errors occurred.
[2017-02-07 11:52:44:520]  http://localhost/AadhaarAPI/api/Aadhaar : Stacktrace :    
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Uidai.Aadhaar.Agency.ApiClient`2.<GetResponseXmlAsync>d__25.MoveNext() in D:\Sujeet\VSProjects\AadhaarAPI\Uidai.Aadhaar\Agency\ApiClient.cs:line 138
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Uidai.Aadhaar.Agency.ApiClient`2.<GetResponseAsync>d__22.MoveNext() in D:\Sujeet\VSProjects\AadhaarAPI\Uidai.Aadhaar\Agency\ApiClient.cs:line 94
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Uidai.Aadhaar.Agency.ApiClient`2.<GetResponseAsync>d__21.MoveNext() in D:\Sujeet\VSProjects\AadhaarAPI\Uidai.Aadhaar\Agency\ApiClient.cs:line 78
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at AadhaarAPI.Controllers.AadhaarController.<AuthenticateAsync>d__13.MoveNext() in D:\Sujeet\VSProjects\AadhaarAPI\AadhaarAPI\Controllers\AadhaarController.cs:line 119
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at AadhaarAPI.Controllers.AadhaarController.CheckIfAadhaarIsValid(PersonalInfo personalInfo) in D:\Sujeet\VSProjects\AadhaarAPI\AadhaarAPI\Controllers\AadhaarController.cs:line 53
```

From my understanding so far, the await/async calls are the ones causing the error. The code snippet for the async call is as follows:

```cs
var apiClient = new AuthClient
{
    AgencyInfo = APIConfiguration.AgencyInfo,
    Request = new AuthRequest(deviceContext) { Signer = Signer },
    Response = new AuthResponse { Verifier = Verifier }
};

await apiClient.GetResponseAsync(); // This is where the call throws an error

var response =  string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiClient.Response.ErrorCode)
            ? $"{apiClient.Response.IsAuthentic}"
            : $"{apiClient.Response.ErrorCode}";
```

Can someone please help me with understanding this error?

Please let me know if any other information is needed. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 RC for my development, if that matters.

**Disclaimer**: The code snippet is also provided by the package developer. I don't take credit for any of this development.

**EDIT**:
As per the comments, the details of the AggregateException are as follows:

[image]

Comment: You will need to know the actual error that is occurring by "unwrapping" the AggregateException. It contains one or more exceptions that will provide the actual exception(s) that have caused this. It could be that it failed to perform a HTTP call (maybe your production server uses an outbound firewall to prevent calls) or the wrong URL was used (maybe your application in production has different configuration) or something else entirely - without the correct exception, you will be trying to fix it blind.

Comment: That line (from [here](https://github.com/souvikdc9/aadhaarapi.net/blob/master/Source/src/Uidai.Aadhaar/Agency/ApiClient.cs)) is `XElement.Load(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())`, although I think it's more likely it's out by one and is the previous line calling `EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` and throwing because your service returned a 4xx or 5xx status.  Unwrap the `AggregateException` (as @RB says) and you should get your answer.

Comment: As suggested, I've updated the details of the AggregateException. It says `Operation timed out`. I fail to understand why does this happen only on local IIS?

Comment: Probably the HTTP call to the server then.  Perhaps you have a different URL configured there, compared to your local one?  Perhaps a firewall rule needed?

Comment: @sellotape no, its the same URL I'm hitting from the same machine.. I don't see why we need to check firewall rule if I can hit the URL from my VS.. Can you help on that?